# Selenium 4 : Getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.WebElement.getDomAttribute(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nosuchmethoderror, selenium4

I am using selenium "4.1.2" with chrome 97. While selecting value from drop down using select class, getting exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.WebElement.getDomAttribute(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
```

Below are dependencies in my project:

```
                    ext {
                selenium = '4.1.2'
                webdrivermanager = '5.0.3'
            }
            dependencies {
                compile("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:${selenium}")
            //    compile("io.github.bonigarcia:webdrivermanager:${webdrivermanager}")
                testImplementation "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:${selenium}"
                testImplementation "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:${selenium}"
                testImplementation "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-ie-driver:${selenium}"
                testImplementation "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-edge-driver:${selenium}"
                testImplementation "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-safari-driver:${selenium}"
                testImplementation "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:${selenium}"
                testImplementation "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:${selenium}"
                testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.5.1')
                testImplementation 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest:2.1'
                testImplementation 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:2.1'
                testCompile("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.2")
                testRuntime 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.2'
                testRuntime("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:1.7.2")
                testCompile('io.github.bonigarcia:selenium-jupiter:3.3.4')
                compile group: 'io.qameta.allure', name: 'allure-junit5', version: '2.11.0'
                compile group: 'org.apache.pdfbox', name: 'pdfbox', version: '2.0.16'
                implementation group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.17.1'
                implementation group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.17.1'
                compile group: 'io.qameta.allure', name: 'allure-gradle', version: '2.7.0'
                compile 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.21.0'
                compile('com.assertthat:selenium-shutterbug:1.5')
                compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-nop:1.7.25'
                implementation group: 'javax.mail', name: 'mail', version: '1.4.7'
                implementation group: 'javax.mail', name: 'javax.mail-api', version: '1.6.2'
                runtimeClasspath group: 'javax.mail', name: 'javax.mail-api', version: '1.6.2'
                compile group: 'net.lightbody.bmp', name: 'browsermob-core', version: '2.1.4'
                compile group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '42.2.14'
                compile group: 'org.mongodb', name: 'mongo-java-driver', version: '3.12.4'
                compile group: 'ru.yandex.qatools.ashot', name: 'ashot', version: '1.5.4'
                implementation group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20201115'
                implementation group: 'com.googlecode.json-simple', name: 'json-simple', version: '1.1.1'
                testImplementation group: 'org.junit.platform', name: 'junit-platform-launcher', version: '1.7.2'
                testImplementation group: 'org.junit.platform', name: 'junit-platform-runner', version: '1.7.2'
                testImplementation group: 'org.junit.platform', name: 'junit-platform-surefire-provider', version: '1.3.2'

            }
```

Any help in resolving this issue is highly appreciated.

Comment: please update pdfbox to 2.0.25 (unrelated to your problem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error message...

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.WebElement.getDomAttribute(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
```

...is the result of dependency version conflict.

---

### Deep Dive

As per *@titusfortner* [comment](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/10051#issuecomment-973164019) in the [discussion](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/10051) you need to crosscheck that everything related to Selenium is set to ***4.x*** and that nothing that requires Selenium ***3.x*** (e.g., Appium 7) is included in your dependencies as *@asolntsev* in the [comment](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/10051#issuecomment-978881869) mentions:

> All implementations of [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52805139/7429447) do override method *`getDomAttribute()`*. It never throws *UnsupportedOperationException* in real life.

---

### Solution

You need to execute *`mvn dependency:tree`* or *`gradle dependencies`* and you will be able to trace the problem as described in this [example](https://selenide.org/2020/11/17/why-proxy-does-not-work-in-selenoid/).

Answer (score 0):

I would try forcing below dependency in build.gradle

implementation (group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-api', version: '4.1.2') { force = true }

NoSuchMethod error occurs when dependency version conflict happens. If you are using lower version Appium, upgrading to following version,

implementation 'io.appium:java-client:8.0.0'

may resolve errors.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).